# moment.js get array of all dates for day of week, week of month between date 1 and date 2

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I need to write a javascript function (which we will call getMonthly) which takes in two dates (which are unix timestamps) startDate and endDate, as well as n and w.

This function will return an array of all dates (formatted with helper function) that are nth day of week, wth week of month within this given range.

lets say we have this...

```
//vars
var startDate = 1478191315; // 11/3/2016
var endDate = 1485993600;   // 2/2/2017
var n = 6; // aka saturday
var w = 2; // aka week 2

//helper func to format into parsable date
function formatDate(date) {
    return moment.unix(date).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
}
```

then calling the function I need...

```
getMonthly(startDate, endDate, n, w);
```

would return an array...

```
["11-13-2016","12-11-2016", "1-8-2017"]
```

I see no simple way to do this, is there a simple way to do this with momentjs, or perhaps a different library that will do this efficiently?

Comment: Saying that you have to write a vanilla js function means to write a function that does not depend on any foreign library. So do you want a vanilla js solution or one using a library?

Comment: What have you tried?  Stating your requirements alone isn't very helpful.  We're not here to just write code to your spec.  Have you searched?  I think you'll find this has been answered before elsewhere on StackOverflow.

Comment: How do you define the week number in a month? There is an ISO standard for week of the year, but week of the month varies according to administrative rules.